# printing special character % in python without extra ' ' around it

Tags: python

I'm trying to print like this

```
per = repr('%')
print('Accuracy score is %s%s'%(round(accuracy*100,2),per))
```

which i hope to display `Accuracy score is 78.13%` it returns `Accuracy score is 78.13'%'`. I don't want that awkward `' '` sticking around my `%`. How could i remove that `' '`? or is there any way to print it?

Comment: use f-strings for example  f''Accuracy score is {round(accuracy*100,2)}% {per}' ... the brackets is for calling variables, anything outside the {} will be literal characters

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can include a literal % with a double %% like so:

```
print('Accuracy score is %s%%' % round(accuracy*100,2))
```

Answer (score 1):

By using `repr('%')` you are adding the extra quotation marks:

```
>>> per1 = '%'
>>> per2 = repr('%')
>>> per1
'%'
>>> per2
"'%'"
```

But honestly, an easier way would be to just put an escaped `%` literal in your print statement. For the `%` you would escape it with another `%`, e.g.:

```
print('Accuracy score is %s%% '%(round(accuracy*100,2)))
Accuracy score is 78.13%
```

Comment: yeah, but i already tried with  `repr(%)` it returns `SyntaxError: invalid syntax`. Seems like it only want to work inside `' '` since it means i'm putting string

Comment: Yeah, this is not a particularly good use of `repr` - `%` is a constant character, just put it directly (escaped) in the print statement for less headaches

Answer (score 1):

f-strings are string literals which provide a readable way to include the value of Python expressions inside strings.

```
f'Accuracy score is {round(accuracy*100,2)}'
```

Answer (score 0):

You just have to use `r'%'` in place of `per` in

```
print('Accuracy score is %s%s'%(round(accuracy*100,2),r'%'))
```

Comment: Raw strings have no influence on `%` string formatting. They are there to deactivate backslash escape sequences.

Answer (score -1):

You could use `.format` instead

```
print('Accuracy score is {}%'.format(round(accuracy*100,2)))
```

Output:

```
Accuracy score is 97.8%
```

Comment: Not sure what the downvote is for? I'd like to understand what I did wrong here.